# Why more than one database connection is showing?

Tags: php, mysqli, connection

elow are some file structure of my website. I have removed unnecessary codes from these example codes in order to avoid confusions and larger code chunk.

class: connection.php (collected from internet)

```
<?php
class connection {
    private $_connection;
    private static $_instance; //The single instance
    private $_host = "localhost";
    private $_username = "username";
    private $_password = "password";
    private $_database = "database";

    /*
    Get an instance of the Database
    @return Instance
    */
    public static function getInstance() {
        if(!self::$_instance) { // If no instance then make one
            self::$_instance = new self();
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }

    // Constructor
    private function __construct() {
        $this->_connection = new mysqli($this->_host, $this->_username,
            $this->_password, $this->_database);
        }

    // Magic method clone is empty to prevent duplication of connection
    private function __clone() { }

    // Get mysqli connection
    public function getConnection() {
        return $this->_connection;
    }
}
?>
```

class: login.php (this class authorize users in the website)

```
class login extends connection{
private $conn;
private $userid;
public $loggedin;

function __construct($id){
    $this->userid = $id;
    $this->set_login();
}

private function set_login(){
    $this->connect();
    $result = $this->conn->query("SELECT status FROM users WHERE userid='".$this->userid.'"');
    if($result){
       $this->loggedin = true;
    }else{
       $this->loggedin = false;
    }
}

private function connect(){
    $this->conn = parent::getInstance()->getConnection();
}
}
```

phppage: index.php (this page is for testing number of connection)

```
<?php
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    include '../classes/' . $class . '.php';
});
$user = new login("75");
if($user->logged_in){
    $db = connection::getInstance();
    $conn = $db->getConnection();
    $query = 'SHOW STATUS WHERE variable_name LIKE "Threads_%" OR variable_name = "Connections"';
    $result = $conn->query($query);
    while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
      echo $row['Variable_name'].'  -  '.$row['Value'].'<br />';
    }
}
?>
```

the index.php will show the following information about connection:

```
Connections - 1026572
Threads_cached - 7
Threads_connected - 9
Threads_created - 42943
Threads_running - 2
```

I am referencing two `$conn` in the above examples, one is inside `login.php` class and the another is in `index.php` page, but from the same `connection.php`  class.

I can know the total active connection from `Threads_running` value. But sometimes I can see that the `Threads_running - 2` and sometimes it becomes `Threads_running - 1` while I reload the page.

So, my question to expert is, according to the classes above, is there any possibility to have more than one database connection at a time?

If no, why it is showing `Threads_running - 2` sometimes, which means that there are more than one connection at a time?